# Formula for pyramid-like sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a situation where I need a formula to comply with a pyramid-like increase.

Let's say I have an initial value of 'N'.

The next time I will have the initial 'N' + 2 additional 'Ns', so that's N*3.
Next time I have N + 2N + 3N, that'll make N*6. 
4th time I have it will be N*10 and so forth.

To represent it easy

1st: N --> 1*N

2nd: N + 2N --> 3*N

3rd: 2nd + 3N --> 6*N

4th: 3rd + 4N --> 10*N

5th: 4rd + 5N --> 15*N

And this continues to a large number.

Graphically represented: https://ibb.co/dNn75w

Is there a general use formula that can be applied to this ?

Comment: Umm.... Isn't that simply an Arithmetic series?: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a classic problem in the basic arithmetic of sums.  It is said that Gauss solved this when we has about nine years old.
$$
N + 2N + 3N + \cdots + kN =
N(1 + 2 + \cdots + k) =
N\dfrac{(k+1)k}{2}
$$
You can see the sum involving $k$ by noting that, when $k$ is even, there are $k/2$ pairs of the form $1+k$, $2 + k-1$, $3+k-2$, etc.  That was what Gauss saw as a child.

Comment: Thanks, I was too tired to process this on my own at this hour.